# Different Java bytecode decompile to exactly the same p-code and java code

Tags: java, classloader, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

I have generated two java bytecode files [1.class](http://ge.tt/api/1/files/3CnYjL92/1/blob?download) and [2.class](http://ge.tt/api/1/files/3CnYjL92/0/blob?download), they are different if using hex file viewer inspect them:

[image]

However the decompiled p-code are all the same:

- 1.class -> [1.java](http://ge.tt/api/1/files/3CnYjL92/3/blob?download)
- 2.class -> [2.java](http://ge.tt/api/1/files/3CnYjL92/2/blob?download)

I can also use jd-gui to decompile them into Java source code and again the two byte code files generate exactly the same Java source code:

[image]

So it looks all good, however when I load the two copies of bytecode into class loader, the 1.class copy gives me the following errors:

[image]

Anyone has any clue?

Comment: Execute `javap -c -l 1.class` and check if all entries in the LineNumberTable are pointing to a valid bytecode index. You could even do a diff with the output from 2.class. This should show you the differences.

Comment: @SubOptimal yes you are right. I did that and captured the differences. Strange that ASM bytecode outline view didn't give me the information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you print out line number information using `javap -l`, you can find that `2.class` has the following line number table for `doIt(String, String, AppContext)`:

```
LineNumberTable:
  line 56: 0
  line 57: 11
  line 58: 19
  line 60: 23
  line 61: 65
```

According to this, line number 61 links to byte code index 65 while the same method is only defined by altogether 64 byte. Accordingly, this table cannot be correct and a validator error is thrown.

Comment: Exactly I captured that also, and now the issue is fixed by removing the LINE NUMBER instruction prior to the RETURN instruction